# Find Y-Axis value from point on curve using X-Axis value

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, interpolation

I think this maybe a basic question, but I'm not mathematically equipped to handle the details.

The problem I have is that I will have a curve such as in the image below and I want to find the y-axis value in relation to the curve from a known value along the x-axis.

I'm also somewhat unsure how to plot a curve of that type below, any pointers would be a bonus for me.

[image]

Comment: Given the nature of the question, I'm dubious that "bezier-curve" is an appropriate tag.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve if you are interested in a (very rough) intro to Bezier Curves.

Comment: I couldn't tag it with curve, I don't know what sort of curve it is...

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you have an equation for the curve, let's say for example, $y = \sqrt{x}$.  The this equation is what defines the relationship between $x$-values and $y$-values.  Given a known $x$-value, you just have to plug that value in for $x$ in the equation to find the $y$-value.  In the example $y = \sqrt{x}$, When $x = 100$, the $y$-value is $y = \sqrt{100} = 10$.

If you are trying to plot an unfamiliar function, you may want to organize your work into a table of sample $x$-values and $y$-values.  List a few $x$-values, and then use your equation to determine the appropriate $y$-values.
Here's an example for the equation $y = \sqrt{x}$.

First, choose some $x$-values:
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
  x & y = \sqrt{x} \\
  \hline
  -1 & \\
  0 & \\
  1 & \\
  2 & \\
  3 & \\
  4 & \\
\end{array}
$$

Then, find the $y$-values, based on the given equation:
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
  x & y = \sqrt{x} \\
  \hline
  -1 & \sqrt{-1} = \textrm{not a real number}\\
  0 & \sqrt{0} = 0\\
  1 & \sqrt{1} = 1\\
  2 & \sqrt{2} \approx 1.414\\
  3 & \sqrt{3} \approx 1.732\\
  4 & \sqrt{4} \approx 2\\
\end{array}
$$
This tells you that some points on the graph include $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,1.414)$, $(3,1.732)$, $(2,2)$.  In fact, there are infinitely-many points on the curve, be we can often get a good idea of the shape of a simple graph based on a few points.

Hope this helps!